# Run an ANOVA with subgroups in R

Tags: r, error-handling, statistics, anova

I am trying to compute a nested ANOVA using R. For that, I have Participants who donate money in different Sessions based on a specific Treatment. My data looks like the following:

```
Treatment     Session     Participant
3             1           0.5
3             1           1.0
3             1           1.1
3             2           0
3             2           0.7
3             2           1.6
4             1           0.6
4             1           0.4
4             1           0.4
4             2           0
4             2           0.6
4             2           0.2
```

My approach:

```
> Data$Session = as.factor(Data$Session)
> library(nlme)
> 
> model = lme(Participant ~ Treatment, random=~1|Session,
+             method="REML")
> anova.lme(model,
+           type="sequential",
+           adjustSigma = FALSE)
```

But when I run this, I get this output:

```
> model = lme(Participant ~ Treatment, random=~1|Session,
+             method="REML")
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = rownames(Fitted) <- origOrder) : 
  attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(y[revOrder], Fitted) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
> 
> anova.lme(model,
+           type="sequential",
+           adjustSigma = FALSE)
Error in anova.lme(model, type = "sequential", adjustSigma = FALSE) : 
  Object has to inherit from class "lme".
```

Is there any error in reasoning on my part? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `model = lme(Participant ~ Treatment, random=~1|Session, method="REML", data = Data)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error message...

Comment: Then the issue is probably your data and you need to provide at least the output of `str(Data)` for further diagnosis.